# Is there any way to catch the onkeydown event of the hardware menu button when using the SupportActionBar and the v7 support Toolbar?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-support-library, android-actionbar-compat

My AppCompatActivity axml uses the Android.Support.v7.Widget.Toolbar and the Activity sets the toolbar with `SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);`. Everything works as expected, however I'd like to override the OnKeyDown event of the whole activity to prevent a hardware button click. It appears that SupportActionBar (just an ActionBar) consumes the event for the hardware menu button and so the OnKeyDown of the activity never catches the menu button click.

I've tried overriding the Toolbar view and its OnKeyDown event, but the SupportActionBar consumes this event too.

My work around was to add a menu item that looks like the Overflow Menu icon and opens a popup in OnOptionsItemSelected. However, this is not ideal.

Answer (score -1):

You can override onKeyDown / onKeyUp handlers in your Activity.

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, final KeyEvent event) {
    if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU ) {
        return true; // Ignore the keypress
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, final KeyEvent event) {
    if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU )
        return true; // Ignore the keypress
    }
    return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: I added these event overrides and they don't fire when the hardware menu button is pressed because the SupportActionBar consumes them. If the SupportActionBar is removed, then they fire appropriately.

Comment: Does your app have only one Activity? You want to add these overrides to your root Activity, the one from which you call `setSupportActionBar`

Comment: I'm calling setSupportActionBar from the base activity.